# spectral projection of an element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm studying Takesaki's Operator theory and I preferred "spectral projection "in the page 43 of this book while he didn't speak about it before. I searched it, but I could not find it. Please explain about spectral projection or give me a reference about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching math.stackexchange?

Comment: @ChantryCargill : yes, but I cannot find anythind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any normal operator $T$ gives rise to some spectral measure $E:Bor(\sigma(T))\to\mathcal{P}(H)$ which maps Borel subsets of the spectrum of $T$ into orthogonal projections in $H$. If you take Borel subset $A\subset\sigma(T)$, then $E(A)$ is called a spectral projection. Search spectral theorem on this site.